# Should Resource IDs be unique in my shared MFC DLLs

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Example: The first MFC DLL has a menu ID_MENU_FOO with ID value 4711 in resource.h. The second MFC DLL also has another menu ID_MENU_BAR  with the same ID value 4711.
The Application (exe) uses both DLLs and calls [LoadMenu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/177ay1x0.aspx). If I want to verify the desired menu to be loaded, I need to call the API method [LoadMenu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms647990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) giving the module handle to the desired dll. Or am I wrong?

What is the best practice to handle resource IDs and their uniqueness in my own projects?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, they should be unique

Comment: But why? Usualy I don't care about the values and just add the resource. But then sometimes the application loads the wrong menu or image or whatever when one of the libs or the application itself got new resources, because the new IDs makes existing resources' ids of another lib not unique anymore.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense, a library cannot have any resources.  The IDE won't stop you from creating them, but they need to be linked into a DLL or EXE to be usable.

Comment: Sorry, I mean shared MFC DLLs, I fixed the question

Comment: LoadMenu requires module handle.  That will have to be the one of the DLL.  Resources stored in different modules can have the same ID, the module handle avoids the ambiguity.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, is that the best practice for this scenario? If so, it were ok for me, but then I have much work to switch my Loadxxx calls to the corredponding API calls taking the module handle.

Comment: Using resources across modules is not a "best practice".  Partition your code properly, a menu is used by a window so just make sure that *all* of the window's implementation details are in the same module.

Comment: @HansPassant You are totally right, that's my answer. Thanks! The DLLs exist for many many years and I never put that into question because they were always there and I don't know why they were created and now there is definitively no reason anymore

Comment: It is fairly common (and not a bad idea at all) to put some (often most) resources into separate "resource-only" DLLs, so the resource is separated from the logic. This is useful (for one example) for localization. You start by detecting the user's locale. Then you load the appropriate resource DLL based on the locale, but have one set of logic to handle those localized versions of what's conceptually a single resource. Of course, you need to do more than that to support localization well, but it's a useful first step.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks for your advice. For localisation purposes I think we should not ran into the problem with non unique IDs at runtime, but you are right, I have to check if we have such problems with our localized modules too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just depends on the Kind of modules you have. Loading a resource alwway requires a handle where to load it from.

If you use extension module DLLs all resource IDs in EXE and DLL must be unique in the MFC. So for Extension modules it doesn't matter where the resource is located. The MFC loader will travel through all Extension modules.

If you just use Standard DLLs in the MFC all resources are separated. Each CWinApp module in the DLL and EXE are separated and all have their own search path and Afx Resource Handle. Also the resource handling is a reason for calling AFX_MANAGA_STATE. It saves the current resource handle and sets a new, and after leaving the function it restores the old.

So it depends what you have and how you want to design your program. Because I have a bunch of extension DLLs I have specific ranges that are used for the IDs in each module. Standard care for themselves without touching the ranges of existing extension DLLs because they are available in the standard DLLs search path too.

I forgot to say: This all is only important if you use the MFC as a shared DLL. Otherwise every module has its own resource handle...

Sharing resources in other ways is possible. You may have your own Loader routines to get them...

Comment: Terminology is pretty much off. There is no such thing as a *"current resource handle"*, and `AFX_MANAGE_STATE` doesn't manage handles to resources either. It manages **module** handles. As for the uniqueness of IDs: A resource ID must be unique per module and **resource type**. A module can contain resources of different types with the same ID.

Comment: Isn't it that the current resource handle of the MFC ) is saved and recovered when using AFX_MANAGE_STATE. In fact the current state is switched... so the behavior changes. That is what I mean: With current resource handle, how you call it what is set with AfxSetResourceHandle? And aren't we talking about MFC. The basic facts that a resource is bound to a module isn't asked here. The problem is: When do you need your own resource ID and when it is possible to reuse one...

Comment: @xMRi We are using a chain of extension dlls each prividing resources. In one dll the IDs are unique per type. xMRi You fit my problem right. One dll is accidentally reusing an ID already used by a delendent extension dll what causes another extension dll above to load the wrong resource.

Comment: My Solution keeps as HansPassant mentioned, we have to think about to eliminate the large chain of dlls grown over the last 15 years. If there are reasons to keep more dlls we will reorganize the code to be wehre it makes sense and not where the developer was working on when he added the code or resource, currently this is random for many classes. We will also think about ID ranges for the final chain of dlls if necessary. I also found some resources that were reused in purpose to enforce a particular resource to be exchanged. I dont like this hidden "feature" of implicit overridden resources.

Comment: We have to (re-)design some things :) Thank you all for your time and helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant gave the answer

> Using resources across modules is not a "best practice". Partition your code properly, a menu is used by a window so just make sure that all of the window's implementation details are in the same module.